# npm ERR! FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/webpack-dev-server failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am trying to install `reactjs` with `npm`, and am using my PC in proxy-free environment. But the following error comes up whenever I use `npm install` command. I searched a lot about this but didn't find any solutions. Please Help

```
npm install webpack webpack-dev-server --save-dev
```

**Error is:**

```
> npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
>     npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
>     npm ERR! FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/webpack-dev-server failed, reason: connect
> ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000
>     npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
>     npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:13)
>     npm ERR!     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:399:9)
>     npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:13)
>     npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
>     npm ERR!     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
>     npm ERR!     at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19)
>     npm ERR!  { FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/webpack-dev-server failed, reason: connect
> ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000
>     npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
>     npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:13)
>     npm ERR!     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:399:9)
>     npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:13)
>     npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
>     npm ERR!     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
>     npm ERR!     at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19)
>     npm ERR!   message:
>     npm ERR!    'request to http://registry.npmjs.org/webpack-dev-server failed, reason: connect
> ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000',
>     npm ERR!   type: 'system',
>     npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
>     npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
>     npm ERR!   stack:
>     npm ERR!    'FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/webpack-dev-server failed, reason: connect
> ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000\n    at ClientRequest.req.on.err
> (C:\\Program
> Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-fetch-npm\\src\\index.js:68:14)\n
> at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:13)\n    at
> Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:399:9)\n    at Socket.emit
> (events.js:188:13)\n    at emitErrorNT
> (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)\n    at emitErrorAndCloseNT
> (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)\n    at
> process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19)' }
>     npm ERR!
>     npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
>     npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

Answer (score 7):

Looks like it's trying to connect to `localhost` instead of the registry. Try this:

```
npm config set proxy null
npm config set https-proxy null
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: @prajwlr Worth a shot.

Comment: not working. I have tried all the possible methods. force clean, update, removed, removed manually. no thing is working